# Mac OSX 10.7 - Startup Program for all Users

Tags: macos, osx-lion, boot, login

Is there away in OSX to have a program launched for each user at login. This mac is connected to our domain so there is no way to know which accounts will be used on this mac in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to create an appropriate `launchd` plist (see the `launchd.plist(5)` man page) and put it in `/Library/LaunchAgents/`.

If you're not already skilled at working with launchd plists or plists in general, there are plenty of launchd plist generators/editors around, and general plist editors are even more plentiful.

*caveat lector: I've never tried launching a GUI app this way, so YMMV. But I should point out that this is how Mac OS X launches things like the Finder and the Dock, so it seems like it should work.*